# Are there guarantees that ANY_VALUE in aggregation and HAVING will use the same value?

Tags: sql-standard

I would *assume* this to be the case, since it seems like an easy optimization and to make things more predictable. Given:

```sql
SELECT ANY_VALUE(country) AS country
FROM countries
HAVING ANY_VALUE(country) = 'US'
```

Is there a database where

```
country
NZ
US
```

Could return

```
country
NZ
```

Because the two `ANY_VALUE` clauses are executed independently?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Charlieface It's a general question on what the behavior is anywhere, since ANY_VALUE has been adapted into ANSI-SQL with the last standard. That said I use RedShift, Athena and BigQuery.

Comment: There isn't really such a thing as the "standard", every DBMS has its own idiosyncracies. You need to look at the one you are using and how it implements this function (or more the point, whether it calculates it differently on different references). SQL Server doesn't provide this function, but I know if it did the results would always be the same, because of how it compiles aggregate functions. You could always just use `MIN()` to be sure, the performance should be almost the same.

Comment: @Charlieface I wasn’t asking for a handwavy lecture on how databases work, I was asking for a concrete answer on how database implementations are handling this. Both ANY_VALUE and HAVING is literally part of ANSI SQL and have defined semantics. If you don’t have concrete answers it’s fine to simply not comment.